# Why does a function literal used as a default argument require a parameter type?

Tags: scala, function, generics, type-inference

This compiles fine:

```
def walk[X](a: X)(f: X => Boolean): Boolean =  f(a)

walk(1)(_ => true)
```

This compiles fine as well:

```
def walk(a: Int)(f: Int => Boolean = _ => true): Boolean =  f(a)

walk(1)()
```

This does not:

```
def walk[X](a: X)(f: X => Boolean = _ => true): Boolean = f(a)

walk(1)()
```

The error is:

> Error:(1, 38) missing parameter type

The obvious workaround is to use `(_: X) => true`, but why is this an error? I though that when the second parameter list is being processed, type information obtained from the first one should already be available?

Tested with Scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.1

Comment: Argh I accidentally removed my comment :) OK yeah, I realized that too, but please do edit it to emphasize the problem (or even better, remove those lines altogether; problem is in the definition, not invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/366). Note that this is the case only for default parameters; elsewhere the inference works just fine.

For example,

```
// works
def walk1[X]: X => Boolean = _ => true

// fails
def walk2[X](f: X => Boolean = _ => true) = ???
```